# Error when building Qt 4.8 (beta) with gcc 4.6.1 on MacOSX Lion

Tags: macos, qt, gcc, g++, osx-lion

I try to build the latest source of the Qt 4.8 beta with gcc 4.6.1 configure fails with the following:

```
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fconstant-cfstrings’
```

It seems to be working with the g++ version (i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2) shipped with XCode 4.1

The reason for this combo of gcc and qt is that i want to try out the new C++11 features available in the latest version of Qt.

Answer (score 0):

I have a same problem but with gcc 4.8.1
but i manually erase it in root project dir configure file and corelib/configure[released|debug]
for now i cant find where is generated.